# How to plot in a loop using par(new=T)?

Tags: r

I would like to plot two sets of values (from different datasets but for the same countries) with two x axes for several countries in two loops using par(new=T). R however overlays the second set of data starting from the last country.
Here you can see the result
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9x0dn7oom5czpwm/Rplot02.jpg?dl=0

Here is my code as an example for 2 countries only (I have 28).

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar = c(5,5,5,5), cex.axis=1)
for (i in colnames(DPreachdifft[,2:3])) {
  plot(DPreachdifft$Diff, DPreachdifft[[i]],
       type="p",col="red", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", 
       ylim = range(c(-25, 25)),
       xlim = rev(range(DPreachdifft$Diff)),
       ylab="delay(+) or advance(-) in years", xlab=NA, pch=16,
       main = i, adj=0)
  axis(side = 1, at=ticks,labels=ticks) 
  axis(side = 2)
  abline(h=0)
}
par(new=T)
for (i in colnames(NPreachdifft[,2:3])) {
  plot(NPreachdifft$Diff1, NPreachdifft[[i]],
  type="p",col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
  ylim = range(c(-40, 40)),
  xlab=NA, ylab=NA, pch=16)
axis(side = 3, at=ticks1)
mtext(side = 1, text="difference in DP", line = 2, adj = 0.5)
mtext(side = 3, text="difference in NP", line = 2, adj = 0.5)
}
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DPreachdifft)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(DPreachdifft, 20))`. And the same for `NPreachdifft`.

Comment: Data are available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd1pwysl6m8ybq7/data.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Problem already solved:)